# I make changes to a form in design mode but when the program is built the changes are not there?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am designing a basic app with multiple forms I seem to be coming across this problem and it will probably be something stupid.

When I make a change to my main form in design mode (like add a button), the button appears in design mode and I can code it but when I build the program it doesn't show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly, your thingamjob isn't gobbling your whatsitcalled.  That's about the best answer anyone can give you without more detailed information.

Comment: Set the Visible property to True.

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

- Clean and Rebuild
- Make sure you're you're starting a correct form in `Application.Run` in `Program.cs`

Most Important of all ..

- Save your changes !

Answer (score 0):

And make sure that the build compiles (it might not compile and not ask you if you want it to run the last successful build).

Answer (score 0):

Check out what Microsoft themselves say:

http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2005/02/04/999.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved. Just go to `taskbar> build >clean rebuild`.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

- If you change the code-behind, does the debugger stop on a breakpoint you put on that change? Also, declare a dummy variable and check if it is visible through the debugger windows such as "Locals", "Autos", "Watch" or "Immediate"?
- Did you tamper with Form's default constructor (add parameters, change visibility, that sort of things)?
- The form you are changing - are you positive that it is actually a main form (check the `Program.Main`)?
- Does your form include user controls?
- Did you try restarting the Visual Studio?
- Did you try a full rebuild?
- Did you try manually deleting all bin/obj folders then rebuilding?
- Is your project actually selected for building under current configuration/platform (investigate the Build check-box under Configuration Manager)?
- Did the project successfully build (check the error log)?
- Are you running the same configuration/platform that you are building? Are you running the same project that you are building?

  - Ensure the right project is bold in the Solution Manager or check the start-up project in Solution Manager.
  - Do you happen to use "Start external program" under debugging options?

*OK, this is not exactly an "answer", but answering these questions may produce some clues as to where is the actual problem...*